IONOS REST requirements for HTTPS POST transaction
I have been attempting to prepare a POST transaction for use by SwiftUI.
The webspace target is IONOS web space.
I have been using Rapid API to generate initial codes which I can then understand and modify.
No matter what authorisation I send I get a 401.
Various SO contributors say that authorisation details for a POST should be in the body
RapidAPI puts the auth into the headers area.
Could anybody publish the REST syntax for an IONOS webspace? Or point to a URL where it is described. I have truly scoured looking for this but cannot find it on IONOS or anywhere else.
